# Sublime Text - spell check does not work for .txt files (while working for other files)

Tags: sublimetext, spell-checking, txt

Sublime Text - spell check does not work for `.txt` files (while working for other files).

Why? How to fix? Any ideas?

Also: in a new file (not yet saved) the spell check works. However, after the file is saved as `.txt`, the spell check does not work. Unexpected. Why? How to fix?

The `Preferences.sublime-settings` has:

```
    "spell_check": true,
```

and nothing special for `.txt` files.

Sublime Text, Build 4126.

---

UPD. In safe mode:
[image]

Here we see that in `helloe.bash` the `helloe` is not spell-checked. Why?

The `Bash.sublime-settings` has:

```
// These settings override both User and Default settings for the Bash syntax
{
    
}
```

---

UPD2. After adding `"spell_check": true` in `Bash.sublime-settings` the `helloe` is still not spell-checked. Any ideas why?
[image]

Comment: Open a `.txt` file, then select **`Preferences → Settings—Syntax Specific`**. Look in the right side pane of the window that opens - is there a `"spell_check": false` setting there?

Comment: Thanks for the idea! No, there is no `"spell_check": false` there. However, I've figured out that `.txt` files are syntax-highlighted as `.bash` files (it was needed by some reason). So, now the question is how to enable spell check for `.bash` (and `.sh`) files. Any ideas? The `Bash.sublime-settings` has no `"spell_check": false` there.

Comment: Just add `"spell_check": true` to the `.sublime-settings` files for any syntax you want. The settings file on the right side of the preferences window is editable, and you can add or change any valid setting in there.

Comment: I did, but the `helloe` is still not spell-checked. See UPD2. Any ideas why?

Comment: `spell_check` controls wether or not spell checking is turned on or not, but `spelling_selector` determines what text is actually spell checked. Specifically, in source code files it's basically strings and comments. In your example the text is a variable name. If you want to alter that, you need to alter the `spelling_selector` too,

Comment: @OdatNurd Holy moly, indeed! The `helloe` in `v="helloe"` _is_ spell checked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple things to check:

1. Check how `.txt` files are syntax-highlighted. In my case `.txt` files are syntax-highlighted as `.bash` files (it is needed by some reason).
2. If `.txt` files are syntax-highlighted as `.bash` files, then `helloe` is a *variable name*, which is *not* spell checked by default. As user @OdatNurd said:

> `spell_check` controls weather or not spell checking is turned on or not, but `spelling_selector` determines what text is actually spell checked. Specifically, in source code files it's basically strings and comments. In your example the text is a variable name. If you want to alter that, you need to alter the `spelling_selector` too.